# IE11 shows a blank page

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, w3c-validation

Our asp.net 3.5 web application shows a blank page in IE11. The page however renders fine in IE8 to IE10. I have turned on Fiddler and it shows that the complete HTML is returned by the IIS 7.0 webserver however IE11 fails when it tries to render the html. Adding the site as an intranet site in the "compatability view settings" makes the site work fine. What can I do at my webserver or ASP.Net application end to make sure that the application renders fine in all IE browsers. I have spend several days trolling different websites looking for an answer but no avail. 
Here is the latest raw response from fiddler:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxQo8ldaJK3ydmpVQnp2bU5RcTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is it a intranet site? Then maybe there's a problem with the compatibility view. Check the browser's setting in Tools > Comptibility View Settings > Show Intranet Sites in Compatibility View (or similar, I only have a german version if IE).

Comment: You should isolate the trouble shooting code, and include it into your question as a reproduceable snippet. This will serve future visitors bettter, even if the linked source wouldn't be available.

Comment: @Teemu, I have attached the link for the raw html response from fiddler. The site also works fine when I add the site in the "compatability view settings" in the client browser but I cannot control the browsers used by our clients. I am looking into narrowing down what the problem could be.

Comment: IIS has had an ongoing issue of not properly identifying modern versions of Internet Explorer. I would look into applying some of their patches to see if this resolves the issue for you: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869299(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Sampson: These patches had not been applied to our IIS 6.0 and .Net 4.0 servers. Once these are applied I will update here the results of our testing.

Comment: We applied the patch at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939/en-us. That did not help fix the problem. We have added feedback at https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/812013/ie11-shows-a-blank-page. Hopefully someone in Microsoft will respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using the deprecated Microsoft Mobile Toolkit to detect mobile devices. Due to this IE11 was detecting the ContentType of the page as "text/xml" instead of "text/html". Instead of using something else to detect mobile devices, I decided to do the following in our aspx page's base page:

```
 protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreInit(e);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

hit F12 and see if the markup is actually rendered. Check out the styles, etc. See if anything is hiding your markup. Use the Network waterfall tab (works like fiddler) to examine the requests, look for any 4XX or 5XX responses. Check the console for any errors logged.

What is your DOCTYPE? it should look just like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If not there is a chance you are bouncing to Quirks mode.

Also are you doing any browser sniffing? If so, STOP.

Comment: The doctype that is rendered is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >. I don't remember seeing any 4xx or 5xx for the page or errors in the console but I will recheck. The style should not have any issues since the page works on other IE browsers. We do some browser sniffing in the application to redirect to a mobile version of the application but all of that happens has happened before the system is trying to render the page in error. BTW, if I add the site as an intranet site in the "compatability view settings" then the site works fine.

Comment: try it with the DOCTYPE is showed. Also what did you see in the F12 tools?

Comment: I get different errors if I change the DocType as per your recommendation. If I fix an error then another one comes up. Eg: "End-tag must match corresponding start-tag name", "Incorrect comment syntax", "the specified entity has not been declared". I get the last error near a &nbsp; Can't I just tell IE11 to render the application as it was rendering before in previous IE browsers. Adding the site as an intranet site in the "compatability view settings" in IE11 makes the site work fine.

Comment: add this tag using the version of IE you built the application for, <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">. But I highly recommend you fix the real issues with your application because it is not a good idea to tightly couple yourself to the past. It sounds like you have a lot of badly forms HTML, etc that really needs to be addressed.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Love=> Adding the tag at least allowed the application to partly render itself but you are right. We have a lot badly formed HTML that needs to be addressed.